# System.currentTimeMillis() returns always 0 on Motorola Droid

Tags: android, motorola

The call to `System.currentTimeMillis()`  returns always 0 on Motorola Droid, Android 2.0.
There is no mentioning in changes to System in the API differences between 2.0 and 1.5, so either it was missed somehow or this is a Droid dependency.
Does anyone know how to get the currentTimeMillis in a way that satisfies Android 1.5, Android 2.0, and all hardware? Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on my Motorola DROID, Android 2.0, just fine. Can you post a project somewhere that is giving you the erroneous results?

Comment: Hi,

When you say a project, do you mean the apk? I could mail it to you. If you mean the code, I can post it here. Anything to make this work!

Comment: Source beats compiled stuff, in general, only because there are more ways people can help you. By "a project", I meant a ZIP file of your project directory contents (manifest, source, etc.), so we could examine it, recompile it, etc.

Comment: Sure, I can zip and mail you the code. This is my first paid app for the Android, so I would ask you obviously not to pass forward ;)
It works PERFECT on the HTC, but fails miserably in the Droid. I have a user sending me log files but I do not have access to the actual phone as it did not get to Canada!
It's very urgent as it is the only thing preventing me from releasing BeMeBlackBox. How would I go about sending you the source?

Regards

Ari

Comment: Well, if you can't publicly post the source, I can't help you that way. https://gist.github.com/7b89d2b36f70d6723265 works just fine on my DROID. http://commonsware.com/misc/CurrentTimeMillis-debug.apk is a compiled application using that activity. It will add an icon named WeightDemo to your launcher. If this works on your DROID, then you have a coding bug. If this fails on your DROID, you have a broken DROID.

Comment: I understand, and I really appreciate your help. Tonight I will get that code, compile and send to my lonely Droid user. I still feel completely in the dark, though. No test phone, and "everything works fine on my machine". Is there any way at all I could persuade someone as busy as you to compile and run my project on your Droid? I do have three beautiful daughters, wink wink you can chose one.... Hey, what if I buy your book today? Will that bribe you? Thanks and regards, Ari

Comment: Sorry -- If I offered that to you, I'd have to offer it to everyone. If you can snip out the section that is giving you grief and post it, then you can get help from me and others following #android on SO. You could also consider DeviceAnywhere -- the three-hour Test Center free trial might be sufficient for you.

Comment: Thank you, will follow your advice and report back. Best regards, Ari

Comment: In the end, is there any hard evidence that System.currentTimeMillis may return 0 ?